# Split a variable into two columns(tried colsplit)

Tags: r

I have one variable called `Date` which is of the format `03/08/2015 09:00:00 AM`.

I want to split the column into two columns, namely `Date` and `Time`. I used  `colsplit()` command as:

```
> colsplit(crime$Date,"",names = c("Date","Time"))[1:5,]
  Date                  Time
1    0 3/18/2015 07:44:00 PM
2    0 3/18/2015 11:00:00 PM
3    0 3/18/2015 10:45:00 PM
4    0 3/18/2015 10:30:00 PM
5    0 3/18/2015 09:00:00 PM
```

But it's not quite as expected. The `Date` variable has 0 and the `Time` variable has the other values. How do I rectify this?

Also, when I try to include these variables in the crime data set, the column names are `date.date` and `date.time`.

Comment: Are you sure you want to split the time from the date?  R does a very good job with date/times and does not handle independent times very well.

Comment: Could you provide me with some specifics as how to handle date/times? Like how to view specific records from one date to another without having to include time as well?

Comment: Here is a good starting point: https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-dates-and-times-in-r/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `tidyr::separate` to divide up character columns.

```
data %>% separate(date_time, c("date", "time"), sep = " ", remove = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

For your purposes, just use substr:

```
data.frame(Date = substr(crime$Date, 1, 10), Time = substr(crime$Date, 12, 19))
```

But I have to agree with the first comment about not changing this to two columns.